# Removing only specific diacritics from text in python

Tags: python, regex, unicode, hebrew, text-processing

I need to remove certain diacritics from Hebrew text. If I needed to strip the text from ALL diacritics it wouldn't be such a problem.

In unicode, the range that I would like to remove is between \u0591 and \u05AF (or 1425 - 1455 in decimal). every other character (letter, diacritic or punctuation) should ideally stay.

input is a text file, output should be a text file as well.
What would be the best way to remove only a range of unicode characters?
or perhaps unicode is not the right direction...?

edit:

this is the code I've been using to remove all diacritics. Any suggestions how I can modify it so that it removes only the desired charachters and not all diacritization?

```
    normalized=unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', content)
    no_diacritics=''.join([c for c in normalized if not 
    unicodedata.combining(c)])
    no_diacritics
    f.close()
```

Would appreciate your help! Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: you could  use something like 
`i=[false if 1425 <= ord(c) <=1455 else true for c in text]`
 to get the positions of the desired characters and
`t=text[i]`
to remove the undesired ones.

Comment: can you include what have you tried already? and why you didn't like? Make the question more specific perhaps? Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Edited. Thank you!

Comment: I would create a function that returns whether the diacritic is in the specific range you want to remove, and then use something very much like your existing solution, simply replacing `unicodedata.combining` with your new function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should do what you need:

```
normalized = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', content)
no_diacritics = ''.join(c for c in normalized if not '\u0591' <= c <= '\u05af')
```

It checks every character for the range you want to exclude.
The expression `'\u0591' <= c <= '\u05af'` exploits lexical sort order of characters, which is the same as their code points.
You could also write `0x0591 <= ord(c) <= 0x05af` or even `1425 <= ord(c) <= 1455` if you prefer numeric comparison.